# SELECT * FROM (SELECT ..) in Eloquent (Laravel4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How to do this query: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) a ORDER BY id` with Eloquent in Laravel4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ElGavilan, I don't know how to do it with Eloquent. (ORM)

Comment: Be specific about what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_, I need to return last 3 results from the table ORDER BY id ASC.

Comment: In this case use simple query and then rearrange the collection using `sortBy` - like in Marwelln's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked it up but couldn't find a way to do it.

What you can is to just create a normal Eloquent query and then sort it by PHP.

```
$query = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
$query->sortBy(function($object) {
    return $object->id;
});
dd($query->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Raw: DB::select('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) a ORDER BY id');
```

Why using Eloquent all the time? It has so many limitations. You have 3 options when querying a database. Eloquent, Query Builder and Raw.

Comment: Thanks! But it impossible do with Eloquent?